# How can I use XCode as a compiler for my custom project?

Tags: xcode, gcc, compilation, project

I have a project and I want to use XCode as my compiler instead of having to do everything manually in Terminal with GCC and ld. How can I achieve this? Are there any good tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

This is apple's introduction to building with Xcode. Hopefully you'll find it useful. 
http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/xcodebuildsettings.html